# Difference between "свидание" and "встреча"?

Tags: словоупотребление, разница

Would anyone be so kind as to explain to me the difference between видание and встреча?

I looked them up in various dictionaries and depending on the dictionary, both are sometimes translated either as "date" or "meeting" and sometimes they're also listed as synonyms but not always.

I found [this comment](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/22342/15865) to a related question which states

> (встреча и свидание are *almost* the same thing)

which leads me to believe that there indeed must be a difference.
I would be really grateful if someone could explain how they exactly differ and when I should use which (if it matters at all).

Thank you very much and have a nice weekend!

Comment: Every *свидание* is a *встреча*. But not every  *встреча*  is a  *свидание* .  A *свидание* is a meeting involving only two people (A *свидание* is a *встреча* involving only two people).

Comment: What you need is a good quality dictionary that lists usage examples, not just word to word translations. [Reverso](https://www.reverso.net) can also be of some help if you can more or less understand written Russian already. Compare: [свидание](https://context.reverso.net/translation/russian-english/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5?utm_source=reversoweb&utm_medium=contextresults&utm_campaign=resultpage) and [встреча](https://context.reverso.net/translation/russian-english/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0). You might need to register to see more examples.

Comment: встреча can be unplanned, свидание is always planned. Встреча is much wider word.

Answer (score 4):

"Встреча" can be as "date" or "meeting". Also, we can use this in the sense of "business meeting" or "appointment".

I can say: у меня **встреча** с одноклассниками. (I have **a meeting** with classmates).

Or: у меня **встреча** с моей девушкой. (I have **a date** with my girlfriend). It can have two meanings either date or meeting. We have to have a context here.

"Cвидание" often means "a date".

e.g.: Мы с женой каждую пятницу устраиваем романтическое **свидание**. (My wife and I have a romantic **date** every Friday.)

But the word "свидание" can mean "a meeting in prison with a prisoner". I know it's weird, but it's so.

Comment: Свидание as a date sounds formal, I never hear people saying свидание in reference to their own dates.

Comment: It's so pity. Which word do you use usual? Встретиться? It seems as friendzone. "Свидание" means a date... period.

Comment: Male saying "я иду на свидание" sounds cheesy to me, more common seems "свтречаюсь с девушкой"

Comment: @Aksakalalmostsurelybinary yes, of course. But I was describing nouns, not verbs. If a colleague asks you: "Встретимся после работы?". What does it mean? It depends on context. But if the colleague asks you: "На свидание пойдешь со мной?". No context needed here.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add, that "свидание" also should be used in the sense of "visiting prisoners".

For example: "Материальная помощь оказывается им в форме обеспечения бесплатного проезда и питания, когда они посещают тюрьму для **свидания с заключенным**.

"Material support was provided to them in the form of free transport and food when they visited the prison to see the prisoner."

Or: "Тюрьмы стремятся обеспечивать максимально благоприятный **режим свиданий** с заключенными в зависимости от количества посетителей в любой конкретный день."

Prisons aim to conduct security procedures at visitor receptions as quickly as possible, depending on the number of visitors on any particular day.